# LinearLayout can't align properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Hi I want a layout like bellow

```
Main amount         120 usd
Extra charge        2   usd
----------------------------
Sub Total           122 usd
Discount             5  usd
----------------------------
Total amount        117 usd
```

I am totally not familiar with constraint layout I tried to use LinearLayout gravity/layout/alignment gravity right for right part but its not working ,all aligned from left.I will be glad if someone give a example code for this layout plz.

Update: my current code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Amount"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="10 "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="USD"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Updated my current code

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of view use LinearLayout with **weightSum** property to the parent LinearLayout and use **layout_weight** for the Children LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:weightSum="4">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2">
       <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Main Amount"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="10 "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="USD"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It was perfect solution for me

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout is going to be difficult without a lot of hard coding of layout_width on the children.  Have you tried TableLayout?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout

TableLayout can be a pain sometimes to get perfect, but it will give you the layout you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't knew about table layout ,let me try on it

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
I used LinearLayout as the parent and add RelativeLayout to it to create align the TextViews the way you want to.
You can dupe the Relative layout the create the rest.
not sure if it's the best way... but it works

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main"
        android:text="amount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/extra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Extra"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/charge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/extra"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/extra"
        android:text="charge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="usd"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usd"
        android:text="120"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usd2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/extra"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="usd"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/extra"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usd2"
        android:text="120"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for this layout you better use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).
It will take you only a few minutes to build this layout, you can add [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to make your life easier.

In addition, your layout will be responsive to all screen sizes so consider using `ConstraintLyaout`

**Here is an example of you wanted layout using`ConstraintLyaout`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@color/bronze"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@color/bronze"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]